# JavaScript on click ul li a href - prevent default not working

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

I understand this question has been asked many times, however, in my case none of the solutions seem to be working. Hence the request.

I am using the following scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="sly.min.js"></script>
```

Through a PHP script, I am getting the `UL Li`'s generated.

```
echo '<p>MATCH FOLDERS</p>';
echo '<ul id="matchListUL" name="matchListUL">';
while($matdata = $matRes->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo '<li style="list-style:none" onclick="matchName(this)" id="matchList" name="matchList" value="'.implode('; ', $matdata).'" ><a id="matList" href="'.implode('; ', $matdata).'">'.implode('; ', $matdata).'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>'
```

within the `li` I have included `onclick="matchName(this)"`.  Through the following javascript code, I am trying to preventDefault

```
function matchName(elm) { 
  var match = elm.getAttribute('value');
  elm.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

I have tried various combinations of the above, including adding an `addEventListener` and `preventDefault`, moving the onclick event from `li` to `a` tag, adding `return false` in `li` tag itself.  Nothing seems to be working.  I am testing this on both firefox and chrome.

I am not sure if `jquery`, `sly` or `modernizr` is conflicting with the preventDefault().  When I run the demo code given in the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_preventdefault) it works perfectly.

Comment: As far I know the prevent default works on the event, not on the element.

Comment: don't use anchors. use buttons.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the prevent default works on the event, not on the element. The correct way of using prevent default.

```js
$('li').bind('click',{},onClicked);

function onClicked(e){
  var target = e.currentTarget;
  //Do what you want to do;
  console.log($(e.currentTarget).text())
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to achieve this without inline event handlers, and instead via jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function(event) { 

    var match =  this[0].getAttribute('value'); // equivalent to var match = elm.getAttribute('value'); in your original code

    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default on the event

    return false; // prevent default behavior of handler
})
```

In this case you would run this JavaScript after your Dom has loaded. You could also remove the `onclick` inline handlers in your current code

Answer (score 0):

You can try vanilla js to stop preventing events.

```
<ul id="matchListUL">
    <li value="1">1</li>
    <li value="2">2</li>
    <li value="3">3</li>
    <li value="4">4</li>
</ul>
<script>
    var matchListUL = document.getElementById('matchListUL');
    matchListUL.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert(e.target.getAttribute('value'));
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Look output at fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b718zefy/6/).

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick, add `event.preventDefault()` before calling the function:

```
onclick="event.preventDefault(); matchName(this);"
```

Alternatively, you can pass the event to the function itself as well as the element:

```
function matchName(evt,elm) { 
  evt.preventDefault();
  var match = elm.getAttribute('value');
  elm.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

And then update your onclick to be `onclick="matchName(event,this);"`